# Trying to understand this simple TensorFlow code

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm interested in Deep Learning and recently found out about TenserFlow. I installed it and followed the tutorial found at https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started .

This is the code I came up with by following that tutorial:

```
import tensorflow as tf
W = tf.Variable(0.3, tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(-0.3, tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]})

print(sess.run([W, b]))
```

For the time being, I'm only interested in the code before it does the training, as to not get overwhelmed.

Now, I understand (or at least I think I do) parts of this code. It produces the result as expected following the tutorial, but most lines in this code are confusing to me. It might be because I'm not familiar with the mathematics involved, but I don't know how much math is actually involved here so it's hard to tell if that's the problem.

Anyway, I understand the first 6 lines.
Then there's this line:

```
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
```

As I understand it, it simply returns the square of (linear_model - y)
However, y has no value yet.

Then, loss is assigned the value of tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas). I understand that loss needs to be as low as possible.

How do I even interpret these last two lines?

I sort of understand tf.Session() and tf.global_variables_initializer() so I'm not too concerned with those two functions right now.

Bonus question: changing the value in the argument of tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer() in either direction (increase or decrease) gives me the wrong result. How come 0.01 works when 0.1, 0.001 doesn't?

I appreciate any help I can get!
Thanks

Comment: ```As I understand it, it simply returns the square of (linear_model - y) However, y has no value yet.``` Why do you think, ```y``` is of type **placeholder**. [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders)

Comment: Good point. What is the exact purpose of a placeholder? Sorry if it's a stupid question. I tried printing the value of y both before and after it had been "used" and it returned an error in all cases.

Comment: Did you even consider reading the docs? I added the link to my comment.

Comment: @sascha I just followed the "getting started"-tutorial. I usually read the documentation when I have a better understanding of what I'm doing (lots of dots, hard to connect), as it tends to be a bit hard to understand early on. I'm not looking for an in-depth explanation of what's going on in every single function, but rather more something that can give me a comprehensible overview of the purpose of each line and the code as a whole. But nevertheless, I'll take a look at the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it, it simply returns the square of (linear_model - y) However, y has no value yet.
>   Then, loss is assigned the value of tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas). I understand that loss needs to be as low as possible.
>   How do I even interpret these last two lines?

You clearly need to go through TensorFlow documents. You are missing the core idea behind TF - that it defines **computational graph**, at this point there are no computations being involved, you are right - there is no "y" yet, no values at least - it is just a symbolic variable (placeholder) thus we say that our loss will be a mean of square of differences between predictions and true values (y), but we are not providing it yet. Actual values start "living" in the session, before that this is just a graph of computations, instructions for the TF so it knows "what to anticipate".

> Bonus question: changing the value in the argument of tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer() in either direction (increase or decrease) gives me the wrong result. How come 0.01 works when 0.1, 0.001 doesn't?

Linear regression (which you are working with) converges iff learning rate is small enough **and you have enough iterations**. 0.1 is probably just too big, 0.01 is fine and so is 0.001, you simply need more than a 1000 iterations for 0.001, but it will work (and so will any smaller value, but again - much slower).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I definitely understand the code better now. By the way, how do would one normally go about trying to find a good learning rate and number of iterations? I mean, there's a significant drop-off in loss reduction after the model has been trained for some time, to the point where training it further won't increase accuracy anymore. Is it just trial and error or is there a mathematical approach to it?

Comment: For linear regression you can prove good/optimal learning rates, but once you go "deeper" you do not. Thus in general it is trial and error, since in non-convex world you cannot really expect that once things "plateu" they will never speed up again - "everything can happen" in highly nonlinear world. There are, however some heuristics, like rmsprop or Adam, which work suprisingly well with relatively little tuning.